# Twilio Say before append Enqueue

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I want to say something before enqueue a call to another workflow.
This is the TwiML using C# sdk

```cs
var _errorPaying = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ActionID = 6, Notes = "Error paying with credit card" })

var enqueue = new Enqueue(workflowSid: _configurationFacility.PaymentCallWorkFlow);

enqueue.Task(_errorPaying);

twiml.Say("I am sorry, I am having trouble understanding you.").Append(enqueue);
```

And this is the xml that I get

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>I am sorry, I am having trouble understanding you.</Say>
    <Enqueue workflowSid="WWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        <Task>{"ActionID":6,"Notes":"Error paying with credit card"}</Task>
    </Enqueue>
</Response>
```

The problem is the call does not reproduce the Say speech, it is just redirected to the workflow.

Does anyone know what it is wrong, why the Say speech is not reproduced before the enqueue??

Comment: That TwiML looks right to me. Does something else happen in the call before this? If you look in the call log, can you see this TwiML appearing as part of the call?

Comment: yes, xml it is from the call log. It is the last entry before enter to the queue.

Comment: Does something happen before this TwiML though?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to play the message after the call is enqueued?

If so, use the waitUrl verb attribute of enqueue. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue